# Setup Project for Windows Service won't build under Server 2008 (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-services, build, windows-server-2008

We've got new machines here for doing development on running Server 2008.

With Visual Studio 2008 we're having problems building a Setup Project which installs the Windows Service - Under Custom Actions then Uninstall, "InstallerClass property is only valid for assemblies".

This builds and installs fine on XP SP3.

Has anybody else had any similar problems?

**Workstation OS**: Server 2008

**Software**: Visual Studio 2008

Comment: How about providing some information about the problem you're having????

Comment: what do you think the post contents is?

Comment: Gareth - what John is referring to is to *specific* errors that you get when the build fails, or any other symptoms that you can provide other than "it wont build"

Comment: Accepted. I think maybe the project containing your installer class didn't build, or at any rate, the assembly being referenced in the custom action Uninstall property cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend against using the VS install project. Use Wix instead, it's easier than you think.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the service in the custom actions otherwise the service will not be registered. Other than that, are you having any compilation errors?

Comment: Sorry I've miss-directed people....its the Setup for the Windows Service that doesn't build.

Ill edit the main post.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when running commandline devenv.exe to build a .vdproj file (in Nant scripts).  The problem was I was not also building the dependant project first, so once that was done it worked fine.

It had nothing to do with the configuration of the InstallerClass property after all.

Answer (score 0):

I did find this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/447a3y7x(VS.71).aspx

Ive made the changes to the Solution and now waiting for it to be tested on a Server 2008 machine - Im still on XP SP3.